# mockito: how to verify calls on real implementation?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I'd like to verify calls to a logger object, so that the real implementation is still called (so I can see the output during tests).

Something like

```
verify(logger).error(anyString())
```

Comment: If you just want to see the output during tests, why not give your class under test a real Logger?  Do you want to verify the output as well?

Comment: yes, as my example code shows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to use [spy](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13) to verify invocations on real objects.

Comment: the link is broken